# iOS: memory allocated using "malloc" auto released?

Tags: ios, iphone, memory, malloc, ios-simulator

I'd like to reproduce a crash bug of my app under memory pressure, so I want to alloc much memory when my app launch and expect it under memory pressure. I use the code below:

```
void *p[300];
NSInteger allocatedMB = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
    p[allocatedMB] = malloc(1024 * 1024);
    memset(p[allocatedMB], 0, 1024 * 1024);
    allocatedMB += 1;
}
```

I expect to alloc 300M memory, and never free it. but I always get this result on my iPhone:

[image]

It alloc only 150M and later free it to only 71M. But it appear as I expect when in simulator:

[image]

I'm not quite clear about this, any answer will be appreciated about why and how I can do this on my iPhone!

Comment: Are you running a debug build in the simulator, but an optimized build on your phone? That entire code should be optimized out by a sane compiler.

Comment: @Blindy the same scheme, can I cancel this optimization?

Comment: You can change the optimization settings under build settings (see "Optimization Level"). Or change the example such that the compiler couldn't reasonably optimize it out.

Answer (score 1):

The memory allocated by `malloc` is not autoreleased. If you do not call `free`, it will leak. Watch both of these two scenarios in Instruments' "Allocations" tool and you'll see heap spike up by 300 mb and not come down (in both device and simulator).

[image: allocations]

The memory view in the Xcode debugger is apparently not showing you everything. In fact, I can't get it to show me the 300mb in either simulator or device. But Instruments shows it to me. (Though, when I run Instruments on device Allocations tool works, but Leaks tool does not. This problem has been reported by others, too.)

Comment: So actually the app is under memory pressure?

Comment: It consumes the memory, making it unavailable elsewhere, which leads to memory pressure. If just doing `malloc` calls, you probably won't see actual memory warning events, but subsequent `malloc` calls will start to fail, returning `NULL`, and if you don't test for that and handle it gracefully, the app will crash.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the code is being optimized out, since the compiler can prove `p` is never accessed, and therefore it doesn't actually need to call `memset`.

Try making the pointers `volatile`: `void volatile *p[300];`